# Rails select form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am probably missing something really simple, but would appreciate a little help here

```
<%= select_tag('filters[order_sales_channel]',filter_params['order_sales_channel'],:multiple=>true,:class=>"advancedSearchFormSelectBox") %>
```

I then want to give the options for select

```
<option value="Web">Web</option>
<option value="Phone">Phone</option>
```

How can I achieve this? I tried this but it wasn't working

```
 <%= select_tag('filters[order_sales_channel]',filter_params['order_sales_channel'],:multiple=>true,:class=>"advancedSearchFormSelectBox") %>
 <%= options_for_select([["Web", "Web"], ["Phone", "Phone"]]) %>
```

Follow up question -: Since I am using the select option in multiple places where my option value is same as the printed string, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: select_tag => itself as a parameter to set the option...Read the link  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is :

```
<%= select_tag 'filters[order_sales_channel]', 
               options_for_select(
                 [["Web", "Web"], ["Phone", "Phone"]], 
                 selected: filter_params['order_sales_channel'] 
               ),
               multiple: true,
               class: "advancedSearchFormSelectBox" %>
```

if your options will always be the same, just hardcode them in the relevant class:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  SELECT_OPTIONS = %w[Web Phone].map( &:freeze ).freeze
  def self.select_options
    SELECT_OPTIONS.map{|o| [o,o] }
  end
end
```

then you can use this in your `options_for_select` :

```
options_for_select Order.select_options
```

I like this solution because you can also use `SELECT_OPTIONS` in validations :

```
 validates :some_attribute, inclusion: SELECT_OPTIONS
```

Comment: Should the name tag be inside options_for_select or outside, both give same results when I view source in HTML <%= select_tag 'filters[order_sales_channel]',
                      options_for_select(
                              [["Web", "Web"], ["Phone", "Phone"]],
                      ),
                      selected: filter_params['order_sales_channel'],
                      multiple: true,
                      class: "advancedSearchFormSelectBox" %>